# Hosted Gitlab: edit canned text on ~/public page

Tags: gitlab

At gitlab.com/public for anonymous users it shows a couple lines of text at the top. As shown below. I have a self-hosted instance of gitlab and I'd like to modify that text. The admin interface doesn't have a setting for it. Does anyone know a good way to edit this text?

[image: modify canned]

Answer (score 0):

This text is not configurable. The only text that you can configure is that on the sign in page per [Branded Login Page](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/customization/branded_login_page.html) documentation.